# Reference 'refs/heads/master' not found error

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode-bots, xcode-server

I'm working with Xcode and GIT to create an automatic build service.
One of the bots looks on the Release branch every 5 minutes and builds it in case there are new commits.
Recently i've been starting to get the following error:

> Assertion: Reference 'refs/heads/master' not found (-9)

This bot is working on the Release branch and not the Master branch.
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to do the following on your build server:

`git reset --hard HEAD`

followed by a:

`git pull --rebase=false`